# Scraping Data from JSON

Tags: json, web-scraping

How to scrape this data, 
  http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://91.134.133.185:5000/viaroute?loc=25.299919,55.376774&loc=25.298738,55.369181

and Extract only **total_time"** to a file?

Comment: Use Python's `json` module? It's even called like that, should have been easy to find...

Comment: I dont know exactly,python i guess would work best

Comment: If you are not using python, don't put python in the tags. Very misleading, I'll delete it now.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fairly easy to achieve this with a little search.

You just have to find some modules to work with `json`, `dataframes` and `text files`, and learn how to use them.

**Steps:**

1 - read json data using `pandas.from_json()`

2 - set `data = df['total_time']`

2 - write `data` using `pandas.to_csv()`

*Simple as py.*

**Documentation:**

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: Upvote, even though the answer just lost a bit of its usefulness now that it turns out the OP doesn't know Python in the first place and just put it in the tags because they guessed it might be useful...

Comment: Thanks,i store my json data into a file and extract the information from fie using the pandas function ,right? Sorry i am newbie.

Comment: No! You'll handle the data into the memory until you get to step 3. Only in step 3 you'll get the info from the memory and write it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
json_string = '''Json data here'''
data = json.loads(json_string)
total_time = data["route_summary"]["total_time"]

f = open("file_name_here.txt", "w+")
f.write(str(total_time))
f.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

I've wrote this program for you:

```
import json, urllib2

url = 'http://91.134.133.185:5000/viaroute?loc=25.299919,55.376774&loc=25.298738,55.369181'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(response)

tot_time =  str(data['route_summary']['total_time'])
s = tot_time + "\n"
outfile = "C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\outfile.txt"

with open(outfile, "a+") as f:
    f.write(s)
```

It'll append each observation to the end of outfile.txt

---

Saving json data to a file and reading that file

```
import json, urllib2

url = 'http://91.134.133.185:5000/viaroute?loc=25.299919,55.376774&loc=25.298738,55.369181'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(response)

outfile = "C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\outfile.txt"

#saving json to file
with open(outfile, "w") as f:
    f.write(str(data))

#reading file with json data
with open(outfile, 'r') as g:
    json_data = g.readline()

print json_data

#Output:

{u'route_geometry': u'{_ego@m}|rhBpBaBvHuC`EuArEUtEtAlDvEnD`MlDvMli@hsEfFzn@QlTgNhwCs@fKwBhF', u'status': 0, u'via_indices': [0, 15], u'route_summary': {u'total_time': 101, u'end_point': u'', u'start_point': u'', u'total_distance': 871}, u'route_name': [u'', u''], u'hint_data': {u'checksum': 326195011, u'locations': [u'AXQDAP____8AAAAABwAAABEAAAAYAAAAIwIAAERwAgAAAAAADgyCAef7TAMCAAEB', u'bOsDAP____8AAAAAAwAAAAcAAADFAQAAFAAAAEJwAgAAAAAANQeCAd3dTAMFAAEB']}, u'via_points': [[25.299982, 55.376873], [25.29874, 55.369179]], u'status_message': u'Found route between points', u'found_alternative': False}
```

Comment: Thankyou,wait let me check i am using linux.

Comment: urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused> It's giving me this error. Thanks

Comment: And What if i copy this code json code to a file,and extract the data from the file.

Comment: yeah... it worked, but after "x" tries it started showing me this error. I guess it's an anti-bot feature from their system to prevent ddos... maybe if you change the location or wait a little more you'll fetch the data.

Comment: And surely you can save the whole json to a file and then process the data from the file. Instead of `f.write(s)` you'll have something like `f.write(data)`

Comment: Okay Can you please fetch the data to the file and let me know the code?

Comment: tot_time =  str(data['route_summary']['total_time'])
NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: Oops... you should uncoment the line "#data = ..."... I've fixed the code here and added a version where you'll save the json to a file.